# node.js with http and https routing

Tags: node.js, http, ssl, https

Currently I make my node.js project create both http and https server.

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(3000);

var httpsOptions = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync(config.https.ssl.ca, 'utf8'),
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.https.ssl.key, 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.https.ssl.cert, 'utf8')
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app);
httpsServer.listen(8000);
```

Also I used this middleware to redirect all http traffic to https.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){  
  var host = req.header("host");

  if (host && host.indexOf('localhost') !== -1) {
    next()
  } else if (req.connection.encrypted) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + host + req.url);
  }
});
```

But for some pages I do not need https connections, say http://www.domain.com/shops/ route.  Can I make this route use http method and all other routes use https still?

p.s: this page request resources from other routes like bower_components, public, ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can find request path as follows, which might help you to redirect your request accordingly.

```
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
console.log(url_parts);
console.log(url_parts.pathname);
```